# repaint() method in cycle

Tags: java, graphics

I need a Cube that will draw in isometric projection, after that I need it to turn around one of his axis (for example Z), this is my [source](http://code.google.com/p/mishkapp-projects/downloads/detail?name=Cube.java&can=2&q=#makechanges), I can not understand how to use `repaint()` method to rotate the cube.

Comment: `repaint()` does not rotate anything, but rather all it does is suggest that the paint manager repaint the GUI. You should have a game loop, often a Swing Timer do the rotation mathematics and then call `repaint()`. You will also want to post pertinent source here, not in a link. Your job here is to make it as easy as possible for volunteers to help you, which makes sense -- since you're asking us to put in effort to help you, it's not unreasonable for us to expect you to put in effort as well so that we don't have to click links or see massive amounts of code.

Comment: Also, sometimes refreshing may seem jerky.  That's because the main thread eats up all your resources, so use a Thread.sleep(10) directly after the repaint(), to give the repaint thread a moment to get its bearings and update the screen.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk: better be careful not to call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the GUI thread (the EDT), lest you put the whole GUI to sleep. If he uses a Swing Timer as I suggest, then this is a non-issue since the Timer does this automatically and behind the scenes in a background thread.

Comment: @Hovercraft, I fully agree... however 10ms shouldn't be a problem as long as it does not happen that often.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk: if it's in his game loop, it will be a problem. The rule to follow with Swing GUI's is to *never*, ***never*** call Thread.sleep(...) on the EDT, no matter the duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at "some" of your code (posted below), and yes, you need to use a Swing Timer for your game loop. Also, you'll want to do drawing in  your JPanel's paintComponent method, not its paint method.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.Math;

class Matrix {
   public double[][] times(double[][] A, double[][] B) {
      if (A[0].length == B.length) {
         int i, j, k;
         int m = A.length;
         int n = A[0].length;
         int q = B[0].length;
         double[][] C;
         double[] e;
         C = new double[m][q];
         e = new double[n];
         for (i = 0; i <= m - 1; i++) {
            // System.out.println();
            for (k = 0; k <= q - 1; k++) {
               for (j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++) {
                  e[j] = A[i][j] * B[j][k];
                  C[i][k] = C[i][k] + e[j];
               }
               // System.out.print(C[i][k]+"                    ");
            }
         }
         // System.out.println(m+"@"+n+"@"+q);
         return C;
      } else {
         throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");
      }
   }

   // This method calculates the coordinates of Cube's dots
   public double[][] dots(double[] angle, String dot) {
      double[][] turnX = {
            { 1, 0, 0 },
            { 0, Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[0])),
                  (-1 * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle[0])))) },
            { 0, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle[0])),
                  Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[0])) } };
      double[][] turnY = {
            { Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[1])), 0,
                  Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle[1])) },
            { 0, 1, 0 },
            { (-1 * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle[1])))), 0,
                  Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[1])) } };
      double[][] turnZ = {
            { Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[2])),
                  (-1 * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle[2])))), 0 },
            { Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle[2])),
                  Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[2])), 0 }, { 0, 0, 1 } };
      double[][][] dots = { { { 0 }, { 0 }, { 0 } }, { { 0 }, { 100 }, { 0 } },
            { { 100 }, { 100 }, { 0 } }, { { 100 }, { 0 }, { 0 } },
            { { 100 }, { 0 }, { 100 } }, { { 0 }, { 0 }, { 100 } },
            { { 0 }, { 100 }, { 100 } }, { { 100 }, { 100 }, { 100 } } };

      double[][] oMat = { { 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
      double[][] am = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };

      Matrix mx = new Matrix();

      if (angle[0] != 0 || angle[1] != 0 || angle[2] != 0) {
         if (angle[0] != 0 && angle[1] != 0 && angle[2] != 0) {
            double[][] res = mx.times(turnX, turnY);
            am = mx.times(res, turnZ);
         } else if (angle[0] != 0 && angle[1] != 0 && angle[2] == 0) {
            am = mx.times(turnX, turnY);
         } else if (angle[0] != 0 && angle[1] == 0 && angle[2] != 0) {
            am = mx.times(turnX, turnZ);
         } else if (angle[0] != 0 && angle[1] == 0 && angle[2] == 0) {
            am = turnX;
         } else if (angle[0] == 0 && angle[1] != 0 && angle[2] != 0) {
            am = mx.times(turnY, turnZ);
         } else if (angle[0] == 0 && angle[1] != 0 && angle[2] == 0) {
            am = turnY;
         } else if (angle[0] == 0 && angle[1] == 0 && angle[2] != 0) {
            am = turnZ;
         }

         if (dot == "a") {
            double[][] A3d = mx.times(am, dots[0]);
            double[][] A = mx.times(oMat, A3d);
            return A;
         } else if (dot == "b") {
            double[][] B3d = mx.times(am, dots[1]);
            double[][] B = mx.times(oMat, B3d);
            return B;
         } else if (dot == "c") {
            double[][] C3d = mx.times(am, dots[2]);
            double[][] C = mx.times(oMat, C3d);
            return C;
         } else if (dot == "d") {
            double[][] D3d = mx.times(am, dots[3]);
            double[][] D = mx.times(oMat, D3d);
            return D;
         } else if (dot == "e") {
            double[][] E3d = mx.times(am, dots[4]);
            double[][] E = mx.times(oMat, E3d);
            return E;
         } else if (dot == "f") {
            double[][] F3d = mx.times(am, dots[5]);
            double[][] F = mx.times(oMat, F3d);
            return F;
         } else if (dot == "g") {
            double[][] G3d = mx.times(am, dots[6]);
            double[][] G = mx.times(oMat, G3d);
            return G;
         } else if (dot == "h") {
            double[][] H3d = mx.times(am, dots[7]);
            double[][] H = mx.times(oMat, H3d);
            return H;
         } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal dot name.");
         }
      } else {
         throw new RuntimeException("Zero angles.");
      }

   }
}

class Paint extends JPanel {
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      // Angles { X , Y , Z}
      double[] angle = { 35.264, 45, 0 };
      Matrix mx = new Matrix();
      double[][] A = mx.dots(angle, "a");
      double[][] B = mx.dots(angle, "b");
      double[][] C = mx.dots(angle, "c");
      double[][] D = mx.dots(angle, "d");
      double[][] E = mx.dots(angle, "e");
      double[][] F = mx.dots(angle, "f");
      double[][] G = mx.dots(angle, "g");
      double[][] H = mx.dots(angle, "h");

      Dimension size = getSize();
      int w = (size.width) / 2;
      int t = (size.height) / 2;
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      super.paint(g);
      for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
         angle[2] = i;
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + A[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (A[1][0]))),
               (w + B[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (B[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + B[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (B[1][0]))),
               (w + C[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (C[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + C[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (C[1][0]))),
               (w + D[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (D[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + D[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (D[1][0]))),
               (w + A[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (A[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + A[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (A[1][0]))),
               (w + F[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (F[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + B[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (B[1][0]))),
               (w + G[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (G[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + C[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (C[1][0]))),
               (w + H[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (H[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + D[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (D[1][0]))),
               (w + E[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (E[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + E[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (E[1][0]))),
               (w + F[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (F[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + F[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (F[1][0]))),
               (w + G[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (G[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + G[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (G[1][0]))),
               (w + H[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (H[1][0])))));
         g2.draw(new Line2D.Double((w + H[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (H[1][0]))),
               (w + E[0][0]), (t + (-1 * (E[1][0])))));
         // Timer timer = new Timer(100);
         // timer.start();
         try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
         } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
         }
         this.repaint();
         // setFocusable(true);

      }
   }
}

public class Cube {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Malakhovskyi BS11-01");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(new Paint());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setSize(640, 480);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }
}
```